# How to remap command+num to ctrl+num on mac

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-bigsur

I would like to change shortcut in applications like Chrome, Safari and Terminal on Mac from `Command`+`1`, `Command`+`2`, `Commnad`+`3` ... `Command`+`9`, to `Ctrl`+`1`, `Ctrl`+`2`, `Ctrl`+`3` ... `Ctrl`+`9`.

Because I want to assign `Command`+`1`, ... `Command`+`9` to Automator Actions that I created.
But applications with tabs are overriding them.

I assign most of my shortcuts in `System Preferences` / `Keyboard` / `Shortcuts`.
But it needs to match with option name in menu. And applications with tabs are changing name in menu to title of tab.
So how do I change that shourtcut ?

Also I don't want to globaly swap Command and Ctrl because I use other shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly - I'd pick something else to run your actions.
Ever heard the phrase "You can't fight City Hall"? … well, this is one of those occasions.

To change this type of command globally, you'd need a global intercept like Karabiner… by which time that would affect everything else you do, in an ever-downward spiral.

If you start your actions all with perhaps  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   then you'll never fall over anything else by accident, unless you're a heavy user of Accessibility options [all of which are either off by default or can be switched off in System Prefs].

Comment: I was looking at Karabiner.
Almost every article that I found was ending with it.
It seem to be solution.
But it require a lot of privilages, and I'm new Mac user, so I don't know is it safe.

Comment: Define "safe". It is trustworthy? Yes. Will it install adware/spyware etc? No. Will it enable you in inexperienced hands to mess up your keyboard so much you will have to reinstall the OS to get control back? Sure.

Comment: I was thinking about spyware etc.

But about messing my keyboard.
Assuming Karabiner is trustworthy. If I won't tell it to remap any letters, numbers, enter key, etc, then I think I will be always able to log in. And then I can use mouse to reverse any changes.
I'm new to Mac, but I'm experienced user on Windows and Linux.
Is it really so likely to accidentally disable whole keyboard or permanently lock a key in Karabiner ?

Comment: No, it's unlikely. Go ahead, give it a try. I've never used it, so I can't help any furtehr, sorry.